# I want to access the calendar through my application using google api?

Tags: google-api, authorization, google-calendar-api, google-auth-library

I want to access the calendar through my application using google api. I'm stuck at the last step. When I want it to be integrated with my gmail account in my application, an address like this is created.

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-10fce901f7-6d36-4955-a211-c96be327deb8@gmail.com
```

I've allowed the app to access my calendar from my Gmail account, but I still can't see the schedules.
What should I do at this stage?